# How to get the values from different rows and same table in mageno2

Tags: database, magento2.3

I want to get **filter_options(804)** value based on the condition **filter_ids=13** and **filter_ids=7** and **filter_options=575** for the same sku.

[image]

How to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Using mysql query ?

Comment: Magento  or MYSQL

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Query :-**

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE filter_ids IN (13,7,575) AND filter_options = 804
GROUP BY
   product_sku
HAVING
   COUNT(*) > 1
```